# Is there a difference between 'fetchone()' and 'LIMIT 1' using SQLAlchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy

When using SQLAlchemy to retrieve a row from a database, you might use

```
query = "SELECT some_col FROM some_table"

row = session.execute(query).fetchone()
```

However, you could also do:

```
query = "SELECT some_col FROM some_table LIMIT 1"

row = session.execute(query).fetchall()
```

Is there any reason to prefer one over the other, e.g. better performance?

Comment: In the secod variant the database engine knows beforehand that only one row is needed and doesn't have to prepare for providing more data quickly (which isn't needed then).

Comment: Also, if you know you are only getting one item, if you call `.fetchall()` with a `LIMIT 1`, you get a collection back with only a single element which you'll have to index out or iterate over to use. Best to use the limit query and `.fetchone()` so you are immediately returned a single row.

Answer (score 2):

The first variant works with all DBMS, the second only with those supporting the LIMIT keyword which is not standard.  So if you want to tell the database you want to limit the result to just one row, you better use SQLAlchemy core instead of an SQL statement as string.  Something like:

```
row = session.execute(select([some_table.c.some_col]).limit(1)).fetchone()
```

If you really query just one row with just one column you might consider `scalar()` instead of `fetchone()`:

```
value = session.execute(select([some_table.c.some_col]).limit(1)).scalar()
```